# Is it necessary to escape double quotes used within Ruby string interpolation?

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation

Given the following Ruby code:

```
my_array = %w(one two three)
logger.info "Backtrace:\n#{my_array.join("\n")}"
```

Expected Output:

```
Backtrace:
one
two
three
```

Is it necessary to escape the double quoted `"\n"` or would that result in the opposite effect?

Comment: What logger? Is this Rails?

Comment: That's where one can see that SO's ruby syntax highlighter is misleading, since the `\n` sequence seems to be outside the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the stuff inside `#{...}` inside a double quoted string (or other-quoted string that behaves like a double quoted string) is just Ruby so double quoted strings inside `#{...}` are just plain old double quoted strings. In particular, this:

```
s = "#{"\n"}"
```

will put a single newline into `s`.

Comment: Interesting...can you have string interpolation inside of string interpolation? `"In#{"sep#{"\n"}tion"}"`

Comment: Yes, Ruby is smart enough to match up the `#{` with the right `}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying such short code passages using [`irb`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) which reads and interprets Ruby code on-the-fly.

Regarding your question:

```
my_array = %w(one two three)
logger.info "Backtrace:\n#{my_array.join("\n")}"
```

is the correct syntax, and:

```
my_array = %w(one two three)
logger.info "Backtrace:\n#{my_array.join(\"\n\")}"
```

will not work. The `#{}` causes everything inside to be treated as a normal Ruby expression without need of special escaping.